# Get Value From sessionStorage and Add To Header

Tags: jquery, angularjs, access-token

I Can get sessionStorage value like this >>
`$window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')` I want to add this token to all header How i can add it

```
get: function(url, headers, data, success, error) {
    $http({
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers,
            params: data,
            url: url
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                success(response.data);
            },
            error);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)

Comment: The function should really return the promise produced by the $http service. Converting the $http service to a callback only API is like converting a jet to a prop plane.